# Groovy: how to test if a property access will be successful?

Tags: groovy, properties

I have a variable Object foo, which is not null. I want to use foo.bar, but only if it won't bomb me with 'No such property: bar for class: Whatever'.

How should I do the following test:

```
if (/*test-here*/) {
  use(foo.bar)
}
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use `object.hasProperty(propertyName)`. This will return a truthy value (the property reference) if the property exists. Also `object.metaClass.hasProperty(instance, propertyName)` is possible. Use `object.respondsTo(methodName)` to test for method existence.

Comment: Beware that this does not work for the case of an undefined _variable_ in the binding, for which you need `binding.hasVariable(variableName)`.

Comment: Does this work on a Map where you can use "object.property" to get the value for the key "property"?

Comment: Damn, my Jenkins groovy script causes `Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod`

Comment: Thankfully in my case I can just use `== null`

Answer (score 11):

I do this in my Gradle scripts:

```
if(project.hasProperty("propertyThatMightExist")){
    use(propertyThatMightExist)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're doing it on lots of foos and bars you could write (once, but before foo is created):

```
Object.metaClass.getPropertySafe = 
    { delegate.hasProperty(it)?.getProperty(delegate) }
```

Then you can write:

```
foo.getPropertySafe('bar')
```

Comment: For me this gives `No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.getProperty() is applicable for argument types: (String)`. Shouldn't this be `delegate.hasProperty(it) ? getProperty(delegate) : null`?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me :

```
Customer.metaClass.properties.find{it.name == 'propertyName'}.
```

Customer in this example is a  domain class. Not sure if it will work for a plain Groovy class

Comment: This works very well when you don't have an instance of the class, i.e. are dynamically creating criteria to find your instances.

Comment: Also, `Customer.metaClass.getMetaProperty('propertyName')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean exist = Person.metaClass.properties.any{it.name == 'propName'}
```

if propName is an attribute ,**exist=true** `// vice versa`

Answer (score -8):

I can't speak for Groovy specifically, but in just about every dynamic language I've ever used the idiomatic way of doing this is to just do it, and catch the exception if it gets thrown, and in the exception handler do whatever you need to do to handle the situation sensibly.

Comment: Yes, I thought that. But I prefer using exception handling for actual exceptions, because it's more debugger-friendly. Thanks anyway.