# How to verify if an object has certain property?

Tags: groovy

I want to use either a value of expected property or a specified default.
How to achieve this in groovy?

Let's look at the example:

```
def printName(object) {
   //if object has initialized property 'name' - print 'name', otherwise print ToString
   if (object<some code here>name && object.name) {
      print object.name
   } else {
      print object
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Groovy: how to test if a property access will be successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240680/groovy-how-to-test-if-a-property-access-will-be-successful)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can use [`hasProperty`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#hasProperty(java.lang.String)).  Example:

```
if (object.hasProperty('name') && object.name) {
    println object.name
} else {
    println object
}
```

If you're using a variable for the property name, you can use this:

```
String propName = 'name'
if (object.hasProperty(propName) && object."$propName") {
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Better than mine...  I shouldn't have started from the metaClass ;-)

Comment: `#hasProperty` actually returns a [MetaProperty](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/MetaProperty.html), so you can also do something like `object.hasProperty(propName)?.getProperty(object) ?: defval`

Comment: ...and there is some inconsistence in groovyDoc (groovy-2.4.7):

_Description_ starts with ```Returns true of the implementing MetaClass has a property of the given name
```

_Returns_ stands for ```The found MetaProperty or null if it doesn't exist``` which is the truth

Comment: The solution provided here and in other responses doesn't distinguish between an attribute that is absent vs an attribute that has the value null since as @TimurMilovanov pointed out it is returning null for dynamic fields as in case of an Expando.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your `object` is a Groovy class, you can use `hasProperty` in the object `metaClass` like so:

```
def printName( o ) {
  if( o.metaClass.hasProperty( o, 'name' ) && o.name ) {
    println "Printing Name : $o.name"
  }
  else {
    println o
  }
}
```

So, then given two classes:

```
class Named {
  String name
  int age

  String toString() { "toString Named:$name/$age" }
}

class Unnamed {
  int age

  String toString() { "toString Unnamed:$age" }
}
```

You can create instance of them, and test:

```
def a = new Named( name: 'tim', age: 21 )
def b = new Unnamed( age: 32 )

printName( a )
printName( b )
```

Which should output:

```
Printing Name : tim
toString Unnamed:32
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, why do I have to access the class property from the metaclass and not in the ordinary way(i.e. object.hasProperty('name'))?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own method via meta-programming:

```
class Foo {
    def name = "Mozart"
}

def f = new Foo()

Object.metaClass.getPropertyOrElse = { prop, defaultVal ->
    delegate.hasProperty(prop) ? delegate."${prop}" : defaultVal
}

assert "Mozart" == f.getPropertyOrElse("name", "")
assert "Salzburg" == f.getPropertyOrElse("city", "Salzburg")
```

Answer (score -5):

If I simply want to assert that an object has some property, I just test the following:

```
assertNotNull(myObject.hasProperty('myProperty').name)
```

If `myObject` does not have `myProperty` the assertion will fail with a null pointer exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'name' on null object
```