# Is there a Groovy equivalent to Gradle findProperty?

Tags: groovy

I'm looking for a way to avoid having to check for the property first with `hasProperty()`.

Ideally I would like to have something like

```
def a = myobj.getPropertyOrElse("mypropname", "defaultvalueifpropertymissing')
```

I see that gradle has a `findProperty()` but I can't find a similar thing for plain groovy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify if an object has certain property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937579/how-to-verify-if-an-object-has-certain-property)

Comment: I have added an implementation of `getPropertyOrElse` to this question (which I believe is the appropriate place, due to duplication) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937579

Comment: That question ask explicitly for a solution to check if a property exists, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I'm asking if there is an convenience method /syntax that avoids the explicit check.

Comment: FYI maps bring that on the table and have `withDefault`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hasProperty` method returns a `MetaProperty` instance that you can use to retrieve the value by passing the original instance:

```
def a = myobj.hasProperty('mypropname')?.getProperty(myobj) ?: 
    'defaultvalueifpropertymissing'
```

And then use the Safe navigation operator(`?.`) and Elvis operator (`?:`) to avoid the `if/else`.

Comment: It’s an improvement although the repetition of myobj still bothers me but it’s better than repeating the property name

Answer (score 0):

The shortest version I could think of is

```
def a = if (a.hasProperty("mypropname")) a.getProperty("mypropname") else "defaultvalueifmissing"
```

which obviously repeats the property name twice. Creating your own method is possible but it's limited to your current class.

```
class MyClass {
    String name = "the name"
}

def a = new MyClass()

def getProperty(Object theInstance, String propName, Object defaultValue) {
  if (theInstance.hasProperty(propName)) theInstance.getProperty(propName) else defaultValue
}

assert "the name" == getProperty(a, "name", "")
assert "default value" == getProperty(a, "method", "default value")
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use `getProperties()` of [MetaClass](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/MetaClass.html) or `getProperty()` of [GroovyObject](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyObject.html):

```
class Test {
    String field1
    String field2
}

def test = new Test(field1: "value1", field2: null)

// using MetaClass.getProperties()
println test.properties["field1"] // value1
println test.properties["field2"] // null
println "field2" in test.properties.keySet() // true
println test.properties["field3"] // null
println "field3" in test.properties.keySet() // false

// using GroovyObject.getProperty()
println test.getProperty("field1") // value1
println test.getProperty("field2") // null
println test.getProperty("field3") // groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
```