# check in Jenkins pipeline if a loaded groovy script provides a specific closure

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins pipeline I load a groovy script like this:

```
def myScript= load("myScript.groovy")
myScript.foo("Hello")
myScript.bar("World")
```

where `myScript.groovy` might look like:

```
public foo(String foo1)
{  println foo1
}
public bar(String bar1)
{  println bar1
}
return this
```

But I have an older version of `myScript.groovy` that doesn't implement `bar()` - how can I check if `bar()` is provided before calling it?
I could use `try` but I think there might be a better way...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to verify if an object has certain property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937579/how-to-verify-if-an-object-has-certain-property)

Comment: Thanks Adam, but it didn't work for me - hasProperty() always returned false...